# How do I make Python 2 the default with Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

I have Anaconda installed which has Python 3 as the default. How do I set Python 2 as my default?

Comment: Default for what? The `python` command should never refer to Python 3 in the first place. You should be able to invoke Python 2 and Python 3 easily with `python2` and `python3` respectively anyway.

Comment: Please describe with an example, what goes wrong, and/or what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

[Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux) has a Python 3.6 version and a Python 2.7 version. Why don't you simply install the Anaconda Python 2.7 version and be done with it?